# tic tac toe, computer can't win (java)

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I'm programming a tic tac toe game in java. I'm not done but I've done some stuff and it should almost be playable. The thing is, I've done the code so the computer should be able to win but it dosen't work. When the computer got three in a row it just keeps on playing when it should say "computer wins!".

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;;

public class Main {

static int[][] gameBoard = new int[3][3];
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //initialize game board
    for(int x=0;x<3; x++){
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            gameBoard[x][i] = 0;
        }
    }

    gameLoop();




}

static void gameLoop(){
    boolean loop = true;

    while(loop==true){
    displayBoard();
    playerMove();
    if(checkIfWin() == true){
        loop = false;
    }

    if(checkIfLose() == true)
        loop = false;

    computerInput();
    }

}

static void playerMove(){
    String playerInput;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Your move: ");
    playerInput = userInput.next();

    if(playerInput.equals("a1")){
        if(gameBoard[0][0] == 0){
            gameBoard[0][0] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }

    }else if(playerInput.equals("a2")){
        if(gameBoard[1][0] == 0){
            gameBoard[1][0] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }
    }else if(playerInput.equals("a3")){
        if(gameBoard[2][0] == 0){
            gameBoard[2][0] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }
    }else if(playerInput.equals("b1")){
        if(gameBoard[0][1] == 0){
            gameBoard[0][1] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }
    }else if(playerInput.equals("b2")){
        if(gameBoard[1][1] == 0){
            gameBoard[1][1] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }
    }else if(playerInput.equals("b3")){
        if(gameBoard[2][1] == 0){
            gameBoard[2][1] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }
    }else if(playerInput.equals("c1")){
        if(gameBoard[0][2] == 0){
            gameBoard[0][2] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }
    }else if(playerInput.equals("c2")){
        if(gameBoard[1][2] == 0){
            gameBoard[1][2] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }
    }else if(playerInput.equals("c3")){
        if(gameBoard[2][2] == 0){
            gameBoard[2][2] = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("That one is already taken!");
        }
    }

}

static boolean checkIfLose(){
    if(gameBoard[0][0] == 2 && gameBoard[0][1] == 2 && gameBoard[0][2] == 2){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[1][0] == 2 && gameBoard[1][1] == 2 && gameBoard[1][2] == 2){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[2][0] == 2 && gameBoard[2][1] == 2 && gameBoard[2][2] == 2){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][1] == 2 && gameBoard[2][1] == 2 && gameBoard[2][1] == 2){
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        displayBoard();
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][0] == 2 && gameBoard[1][0] == 2 && gameBoard[2][0] == 2){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[2][0] == 2 && gameBoard[2][1] == 2 && gameBoard[2][2] == 2){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][2] == 2 && gameBoard[1][2] == 2 && gameBoard[2][2] == 2){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][0] == 2 && gameBoard[1][1] == 2 && gameBoard[2][2] == 2){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][2] == 2 && gameBoard[1][1] == 2 && gameBoard[2][0] == 2){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nComputer wins!");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

static boolean checkIfWin(){
    if(gameBoard[0][0] == 1 && gameBoard[0][1] == 1 && gameBoard[0][2] == 1){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[1][0] == 1 && gameBoard[1][1] == 1 && gameBoard[1][2] == 1){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[2][0] == 1 && gameBoard[2][1] == 1 && gameBoard[2][2] == 1){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][1] == 1 && gameBoard[2][1] == 1 && gameBoard[2][1] == 1){
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        displayBoard();
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][0] == 1 && gameBoard[1][0] == 1 && gameBoard[2][0] == 1){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[2][0] == 1 && gameBoard[2][1] == 1 && gameBoard[2][2] == 1){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][2] == 1 && gameBoard[1][2] == 1 && gameBoard[2][2] == 1){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][0] == 1 && gameBoard[1][1] == 1 && gameBoard[2][2] == 1){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        return true;
    }else if(gameBoard[0][2] == 1 && gameBoard[1][1] == 1 && gameBoard[2][0] == 1){
        displayBoard();
        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

static void displayBoard(){

    System.out.println("  A B C");
    for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
        if(x>0)
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(x+1 + " ");
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){

            if(i>0)
            System.out.print(" ");

        System.out.print(gameBoard[x][i]);
        }
    }
}

static void computerInput(){
    int x;
    int y;
    boolean loop = true;

    while(loop == true){

        x = 0;
        y = 0;

    x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 2 + 1);
    y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 2 + 1);


    if(gameBoard[y][x] == 0){
        gameBoard[y][x] = 2;
        loop = false;
    }

    }
}


}
```

Comment: I think this is one to use your debugger on :)

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr They're there?

Comment: Since the computer input runs after the loop is set to false, it will certainly make on more play after the decision, since the loop will finish its iteration. If you wrap the computermove with an if(loop), it might solve your problem

Comment: I just used your code and got "Computer wins!"? What is the problem?

Comment: Who upvoted this question?! This is a prime example of something that is solved EASILY by debugging his own code.

Comment: Please do not **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/307719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void gameLoop(){
    boolean loop = true;

    while(loop==true){
        displayBoard();
        playerMove();
        if(checkIfWin() == true){
            loop = false;
        }

        if(checkIfLose() == true)
            loop = false;

        If(loop){
            computerInput();
        }
    }

}
```

Adding a loop check for the computer input makes sure that it wont trigger a new move if the game is already settled in that iteration

Comment: @redFIVE:  was writing that on my cell, so please give me at least two minutes to add the comment after trying to preview the code before you start downvoting

Comment: `== true` is redundant

Comment: Well, for sure, that part was copied off the initial post, just added it to show the correct context.